# how to I set default server side encryption of bucket using .net sdk?

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want property of the s3 bucket default encryption to be aes256 but I don't see where I can do that with the .net sdk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following method:

```
public virtual PutBucketEncryptionResponse PutBucketEncryption(
         PutBucketEncryptionRequest request
)
```

Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/S3/MS3PutBucketEncryptionPutBucketEncryptionRequest.html

Comment: much thanks.  seems I had a slightly older aws sdk.  once I updated those classes showed up.